# Using a timer in java Error

Tags: java

```
 public void setTimerCount(View view){
        int value5;
        final double timerCountSeconds = 0;

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timerCountSeconds ++ 0.1;
                timerCount.setText("" + (timerCountSeconds));

            }
        };
```

I think this is right but i get this error on the call of the variable in the run function "Not a Statement

Comment: timerCountSeconds ++ 0.1; is not a statement

Comment: And by variable in thhe run function i mean the entire statement 'timerCountSeconds ++ 0.1;'

Comment: right i chahnged that to one + and thatts the error i get

Comment: sorry for that mistake

Comment: it now reads timerCountSeconds + 0.1; i still get the same error

Comment: thanks for that but know i get an error "variable 'timerCountSeconds' is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final. But when i declare final i get the same error.

Comment: @EliasRC see my answer below.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is local classes can't access variables outside the class. I am not sure that this is the issue, but it is a hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
public void setTimerCount(View view){
    int value5;
    final double timerCountSeconds = 0;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //timerCountSeconds ++ 0.1; is not valid java syntax
            timerCountSeconds =timerCountSeconds+ 0.1;
            timerCount.setText("" + (timerCountSeconds));

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

`final double timerCountSeconds = 0;`

You are trying to change the value of a final variable...

`timerCountSeconds ++ 0.1;`

You probably meant to use `timerCountSeconds += 0.1;`

Try this code:

```
public void setTimerCount(View view) {
    int value5;
    final double[] timerCountSeconds = {0};

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timerCountSeconds[0] += timerCountSeconds[0] + 0.1;
            timerCount.setText("" + (timerCountSeconds[0]));

        }
    };
}
```